# WLAN ping higher with local addresses than external

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, hotspot

I am trying to understand why does my WLAN have such high ping. I set it up with AP hosting with `hostapd`.

When I ping one device to another, for example pc to phone and the other way around, trip time is anywhere from 4ms to 2000ms. That's completely unreliable. I can ping google from same WLAN with constant 22ms.

Clearly there must be something my devices are doing that causes such high ping. I have tested Windows, Ubuntu, Android and it's always unreliable.

[image]

Comment: It’s probably mostly about power-saving, especially with mobile devices. They need to wake up before they can respond to the echo request. It’s also not unreliable if don’t have timeouts. If you want a consistently low-latency transport, Wi-Fi is not an appropriate choice.

Comment: @DanielB Ping to google (around 22) is more than fast enough. Huge spikes are the problem

Comment: But *are* they a problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you ping from PC to Mobile device, the latency will be longer.  The reason for this is because the mobile device must do 802.11 power save to preserve it's battery life.  To explain this as simple as possible, the AP must tell the AP to hold/buffer the data for a specific beacon period.  After the beacon period is reached, the mobile device wakes up and asks for it's buffered data.  This causes latency.  This is normal and you have nothing to worry about.  Ping from your PC to google, this will have less latency because the laptop either is connected to power (which stops the process of 802.11 power save) or the power saving process is different than a mobile device because of battery size.  Regardless, this is all very normal behavior.